# ¿Por qué se ejecuta tantas veces mi switch?

Tags: java

Soy novat@ en esto de programación, y no entiendo que es lo que sucede con este código.

Se supone que le pide un número al usuario ente el 12 y el 5 y muestra las combinaciones de tres números menores que ese, cuya suma sea igual a ese número, lo hice así a la rápida, con *print* ya que no se otra manera.

Pero el problema radica en que cuando le das un numero entre el 12 y el 5 el *print* se repite muchas veces. y no se como detener eso.

```
public static void sumas() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   
    System.out.println("dame un numero ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    
    while (n>0) {
        try { 
            if (n<5 || n>12) {
                System.out.println("dame un numero ");
                n = sc.nextInt();
            } else {
                switch (n) {
                    case 5:
                        System.out.println("3+1+1 " + "2+1+2 ");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        System.out.println("1+2+3 " + "4+1+1 "+ "2+2+2 ");  
                        break;
                    case 7:  
                        System.out.println("1+1+5 " + "1+2+4 "+ "1+3+3 " + "2+2+3 ");  
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        System.out.println("2+3+3 " + "4+2+2 "+ "4+3+1 " + "6+1+1 " + "5+2+1 ");
                        break;
                    case 9: 
                        System.out.println("1+2+6 " + "2+3+4 "+ "3+4+2 "+"2+2+5 "+ "3+3+3 "+ "7+1+1 "); 
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        System.out.println("1+2+7 " + "2+3+5 "+ "3+4+3 "+"4+5+1 "+"6+3+1 "+"7+2+1 "+"8+1+1 "); 
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        System.out.println("1+2+8 " + "2+3+6 "+ "3+4+4 "+"4+5+2 "+"5+3+3 "+"6+1+4 "+"7+2+2 "+"8+2+1 " + "9+1+1");  
                        break;
                    case 12:   
                        System.out.println("1+2+9" + "2+3+7"+ "3+4+5 "+ "4+5+3 "+"5+6+1 "+ "6+3+3 "+"8+2+2"+ "10+1+1");  
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
          System.out.println("¡Cuidado! Solo puedes insertar números. ");
            sc.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En el else -- switch no estás cambiando el valor que se está revisando; en el if vuelves a pedir otro número. Así pues, seguirá cayendo en el else por siempre

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si inicias en la programación es demasiado importante revisar como funcionan [los operadores relacionales y lógicos en Java](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-6957/chp-typeopexpr/index.html), de acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> el problema radica en que cuando le das un numero entre el 12 y el 5
> el print se repite muchas veces.

Se debe a que de acuerdo a tu código si introduces un número menor que 5 o mayor que 12 vuelve a preguntar el valor de `n`, pero si introduces un valor de 5 o mayor y menor de 12 no preguntará y tu programa entraría a un ciclo ya que no vuelve a requerir el valor de `n`.

```
 ...
 ...
 if (n<5 || n>12) {
     System.out.println("dame un numero ");
     n = sc.nextInt();
 } else {  //Se cicla ya que no vuelve a requerir el valor de "n"
     switch (n) { 
     ...
     ...
     }
 } 
 ...
 ...
```

Si deseas que termine cuando introduces un valor  de 5 o mayor y menor de 12 ( que es cuando se cicla tu programa) simplemente tienes que asignar un valor de 0 a la variable n que es como se determina tu `while` debe terminar.

```
 ...
 ...
while (n>0) {
    try { 
        if (n<5 || n>12) {
            System.out.println("dame un numero ");
            n = sc.nextInt();
        } else {  
            switch (n) { 
            ...
            ...
            }
            n=0; //Provoca que termine el "while".
       } 
    }
 ...
 ...
```